# Why does :only care if "Other window contains changes"?

Tags: vim-windows

I have two windows that I created with a `:vsplit`. Window 1 displays a file with changes that have not been saved yet, Window 2 displays another file.

I want to get rid of Window 1, so I type `:only` in Window 2. However, vim complains that `E445: Other window contains changes` and refuses to proceed.

I appreciate that it tells me this but I don't understand why it doesn't proceed. I'm not leaving, why should it care?

Comment: Notice that Vim's session also stores `slient only` on line 4, which might introduce this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim doesn't close the windows because you don't have either of the `'hidden'` or `'autowrite'` options set (which indicates to Vim that you don't *want* windows with unsaved changes to be easily closable).

`:help :only` (or `:help E445`) gives more details:

> When the 'hidden' option is set, all buffers in closed windows become hidden.
>
> When 'hidden' is not set, and the 'autowrite' option is set, modified buffers are written. Otherwise, windows that have buffers that are modified are not removed, unless the [!] is given, then they become hidden. But modified buffers are never abandoned, so changes cannot get lost.

See also `:help hidden-buffers` for more details of how Vim handles this.

Answer (score 1):

Vim generally has a policy of not getting rid of windows with changes unless you *force* it with `!`.

```
:only!
```